# What scenarios could create the need to increase the stack size of the Java JVM?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, stack

I only learnt today that it is possible to set the size of the stack memory in the Java JVM. Now what I'm wondering is when would you ever have the need to do this?

I can't think of any concrete examples where this might be necessary. I've only gotten StackOverFlowExceptions when I've stuffed something up in my code, like an infinite recursion or something.

Comment: It's possible to get SOE's from just recursing too deeply, even if it's not infinite - this is relatively rare in a language like Java because people don't tend to use it for deep recursive stuff, but it can happen. Generally if you need a *really* big stack though, then you've probably screwed up your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the stack size does not necessarily mean increasing it. ;-)

You might need to *increase* the stack size if you have very deep recursion.

You might need to *decrease* the stack size if you are running on a 32-bit JVM and have lots of threads. Each thread has a separate stack that takes up address space, and address space is a scarce resource.

Comment: +1 The JVM doesn't do tail call optimisation which means it can need deeper stacks than the same algo in other languages which do.

Comment: I have a follow-up question - is there a tool out there that would allow me to visualise the current state of the JVM? Like, can I see what threads currently exist, how much stack memory they have allocated, what the heap looks like, what's in the classloader etc?

Comment: @cookiemonster Some details (e.g. infos about current threads) can be obtained with jVisualVM (in your jdk/bin directory), but not all that you mentioned. E.g. it only tells you which threads are running, but nothing about their stack size (although you could possibly derive this info), and it tells you how many classes are loaded, but can not list them all (it may be a few thousand...)

Comment: @cookiemonster: Why not post the follow-up as a separate question?